# Can we use Apache ignite with spring application without running separate ignite cluster

Tags: java, spring, ignite

I'm working with a project that has scalability issues due to cache management and full resource management.

I decide to use Apache Ignite as my caching layer but I don't want to up the separate cluster for that. Can we use my spring application as a cluster node, and there are several other instances together that make the ignite cluster, and also The same application act as ignite client. It will use my unused JVM.

Comment: You may find this https://github.com/ashishb888/ignite-poc useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

You need to configure [Static IP Finder](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-static-ip-finder) to only use `127.0.0.1` host, use the same `localHost`/`localAddress`, use some custom discovery port to avoid interference with any other clusters. You can also try implementing no-op Discovery, but I don't think it is worth the hassle.

An Ignite node can do everything that client node can, so you never need to spawn a separate client if you already possess a (server) node.

As for Spring integration, you can use `IgniteSpringBean` or just manage Ignite lifecycle on its own.

Comment: thanks for the clearing my doubt about the separate client.

Comment: i want to know like i have multiple instances of the same application hosted on AWS, now i want all instances to communicate with each other and work as a distributed cache

Comment: i want my application node act as part of the ignite ring so that they can share the data

Comment: @Devratna You can do that, you will just have to supply correct discovery (such as SharedFs, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Ignite can be deployed in the embedded mode. However, please check all the pros and cons of all the deployment options before you select one: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/deployment-modes#application-deployment-modes